# Firepath shows matching nodes but does not print

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to capture the prices in a list and print them. However the execution stops in the search result page and does not print the prices. I think it is because of the level of Xpath (probably I am not selecting from the upper levels?). I am confused because the Xpath I have created, when I use that in the Firepath it selects 39 matching nodes.

Thanks in advance for your time and advice.

Code:

```
import java.util.List;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Flight {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    //This following section is for browser and getting the url
    public static WebDriver browser(){

        driver= new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.orbitz.com/Flights");
        return driver;

    }

    //this following section is getting the properties of the page      
    public static void  getPageProperties(String ff,String ft, String fd, String rd){

        WebElement flyFrom= driver.findElement(By.id("flight-origin"));
        WebElement flyTo= driver.findElement(By.id("flight-destination"));
        WebElement flyDate= driver.findElement(By.id("flight-departing"));
        WebElement returnDate= driver.findElement(By.id("flight-returning"));
        WebElement flight_search_btn= driver.findElement(By.id("search-button"));

        flyFrom.sendKeys(ff);
        flyTo.sendKeys(ft);
        flyDate.sendKeys(fd);
        returnDate.sendKeys(rd);
        flight_search_btn.click();

    }

    // this following section will have the arguments that we will provide for flight search
    public static void testFligthSearch(){

        Flight f= new Flight();
        f.browser();
        f.getPageProperties("MSP", "SEA", "05/01/2017", "05/05/2017");

        List<WebElement> pricelist= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'dollars')]"));

        for(WebElement e: pricelist){

            System.out.println("The prices are: " + e.getText());
        }

    }

    public static void main (String [] args){

        Flight f= new Flight();
        f.testFligthSearch();

    }
}
```

Problem: No price is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this problem because all the results have not been loaded yet so you have to wait until all search results are loaded, so you need to wait until the search results progress bar has reached 100% as following :

WebElement progressBar = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#acol-interstitial > div > div"));

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(progressBar, "style", "width: 100%;"));

    List<WebElement> pricelist= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#flightModuleList  div.offer-price.urgent > span.visuallyhidden"));

    for(WebElement e: pricelist){

        System.out.println("The prices are: " + e.getText());
    }
```